# Фатальная ошибка Woocommerce: get_billing_country()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

После обновления Wordpress (4.8) and Woocommerce (3.0.8) до последних версий стала появляться такая ошибка..

При попытке повторно отправить счет клиенту из меню «Заказ Действия»:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Генерируется такая ошибка:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function get_billing_country() on boolean in..**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот **273 (я)** строка файла **class-wc-gateway-bacs.php** на которую ругается:

`// Get the order country and country $locale
     $country       = $order->get_billing_country();
     $locale        = $this->get_country_locale();`

Функция **get_billing_country()** объявляется в **class-wc-customer.php** следующим образом:

```
/**
 * Get billing_country.
 *
 * @param  string $context
 * @return string
 */
public function get_billing_country( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_address_prop( 'country', 'billing', $context );
}
```

Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Суть такой ошибки php в том, что функция get_biiling_country () вызывается не у объекта, а у переменной типа boolean. В данном случае это означает, что $order - не объект, а переменная типа boolean (очевидно, false). Где-то раньше по коду не удается получить объект заказ в переменную $order. Почему -  сказать сложно, не видя кода.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо за ответ! Код class-wc-gateway-bacs.php лежит тут https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php,  а class-wc-customer.php тут https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-customer.php Буду очень признателен за ревью, если будет время.

Comment: Я думаю, что сам код WooCommerce работает без ошибок, дело в каких-то сторонних плагинах или модификациях в теме. Попробуйте отключить все плагины и сменить тему на бесплатную StoreFront от WooCommerce и проверить.

Answer (score -1):

`billing_country` - страна указанная в счете.
возможно при оформлении заказов у вас это поле пропущено.

также попробуйте сделать первичную диагностику для локализации проблемы https://wpcraft.ru/2017/kak-najti-prichinu-problemy-v-woocommerce/